Slope and GCD points
given a slope in the form $y=ax+b$
My question is to know if there are (and if yes how to find them) points $(x,y)$ where :
$gcd(x,y)>1$ (to be more precise, the $gcd$ is made between the $x$ and the $y$ of the coordinates of that point). Of course values of $x$ and $y$ must be integral (like 5,13,71) and not real (like 3.11234, 8,044444, ecc).
I am sure that for certain values of $a$ and $b$, there are no points like that, but, in general, how to fine these points ?
Many thanks in advance

Hint: $,(x,y) = (x,ax+b) = (x,b) = 1$ for all $x!\iff! |b| = 1\ \ $

Sorry, I am not sure to have understood.

You need to say what is not clear if you want further elaboration.

bill, thanks for answering, but how can you say (x,ax+b) = (x,b) ? And then it equals to 1 ? I need to find points (x,y) where gcd(x,y) is different than 1

$(m,n):=\gcd(m,n),$ is standard notation in number theory, so in my comment those tuples denote gcds not points.

ok, now I understand. So following your hint you mean that for all x we have |b|= 1 ? For example : y=-2x+15. It has a point (6;3) which satisfies the condition :gcd(6,3) > 1. Why , in this case, |b| should be 1 ?

The comment says that the gcd is $1$ for all points iff $|b|=1$. If $|b|>1$ then it is clear how to chose $x$ so $(x,y) = (x,b)>1,,$ e.g. choose $x = b.\ \ $

Yes, ok thanks. But in my example, how would you sort out the point (6;3) ?

We can choose $x$ to be any nontrivial factor of $b$ to get $(x,b)>1$. There you have the factor $x=3$ of $b=15.\ \ $

Ok, so I assume that the only way is to find the nontrivial factors of b. And that there is not any other way
